# select database on userid and password condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have two databases and I want to select a database on userid password condition, but right now it is not working with this condition. How can I achieve it? For now, only the first database gets selected, not the second one.

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['s_activId'] == 'om' && isset($_SESSION['s_userType']) == 'om')
    {
      $dbName = "kal";
      $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      mysql_select_db($dbName) or die("colud not connect to database". mysql_error());
    }
    else if($_SESSION['s_activId'] == 'om' && isset($_SESSION['s_userType']) == 'om1')
    {
      $dbName = "kal1";
      $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      mysql_select_db($dbName) or die("colud not connect to database". mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql use mysqli, and maybe try mysqli_close();?

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['s_userType']) == 'om'` and `isset($_SESSION['s_userType']) == 'om1'` aren't right.

Comment: than wat should i do @JonStirling

Comment: @omtechnoplus Fix them? `isset` returns true / false, not the value of the variable you're checking.

Comment: You should select an answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `$_SESSION` in a script you must start the session or it is not visible.

Also the If tests needed a little correction, `isset()` returns a boolean and not the data held in the array occurance.

```
<?php
// add this to gain access to the session
session_start();

if($_SESSION['s_activId'] == 'om' && 
   isset($_SESSION['s_userType']) && 
   $_SESSION['s_userType'] == 'om')
{
    $dbName = "kal";
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db($dbName) or die("could not connect to database". mysql_error());
}
else if($_SESSION['s_activId'] == 'om' && 
        isset($_SESSION['s_userType']) && 
        $_SESSION['s_userType'] == 'om1')
{
    $dbName = "kal1";
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db($dbName) or die("could not connect to database". mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: `start_session()`? I thought it should be `session_start()`.

Comment: YUP. I am having a fat finger day, thanks @NaijaProgrammer

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in D:\wamp\www\kal1\checkLogin.php on line 16

Comment: I dont see a `mysql_fetch_array()` in your question, but remember to use `mysql_fetch_array($result)` where `$result` comes from the previous `$result = mysql_query("select .....")`

Comment: I also dont see you accepting any answers or upvoting any that helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

session_start(); //starts the session, then you can access its members

if($_SESSION['s_activId'] == 'om' && $_SESSION['s_userType'] == 'om')
{
    $dbName = "kal";
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db($dbName) or die("could not connect to database". mysql_error());
}
else if($_SESSION['s_activId'] == 'om' && $_SESSION['s_userType'] == 'om1')
{
    $dbName = "kal1";
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db($dbName) or die("could not connect to database". mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `isset` to a string, since it returns true/false.
Also you must use `session_start()` in a file where you will use sessions.

Fixing your code it would be:

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['s_activId']) && isset($_SESSION['s_userType']
    && $_SESSION['s_activId'] == 'om' && $_SESSION['s_userType']=='om')
    {
      $dbName = "kal";
      $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      mysql_select_db($dbName) or die("colud not connect to database". mysql_error());
    }
    else if(isset($_SESSION['s_activId']) && isset($_SESSION['s_userType']
    && $_SESSION['s_activId'] == 'om1' && $_SESSION['s_userType']=='om1')
        {
      $dbName = "kal1";
      $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      mysql_select_db($dbName) or die("colud not connect to database". mysql_error());
    }

?>
```

But a better approach for this code would be to use mysqli since mysql is deprecated.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['s_activId']) && isset($_SESSION['s_userType'] )
    {
      if ($_SESSION['s_activId'] == 'om' && $_SESSION['s_userType']=='om')
      {
        $dbName = "kal";
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", $dbName);
      }
      else if($_SESSION['s_activId'] == 'om1' && $_SESSION['s_userType']=='om1') 
      {
        $dbName = "kal1";
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",$dbName);
      }
    } 
?>
```

That should work.

If you are using other mysql functions the second code won't work unless you change all of them to mysqli.

For example `mysql_fetch_array($result)` would become `mysqli_fetch_array($link, $result)`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')' in D:\wamp\www\kal1\include\conn.php on line 4

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'kal' (11004) in D:\wamp\www\kal1\include\conn.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in D:\wamp\www\kal1\checkLogin.php on line 16

Comment: The parameter order were wrong in the mysqli_connect. It's fixed now.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in D:\wamp\www\kal1\checkLogin.php on line 16

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use **mysql_** functions. They are deprecated. Use **mysqli_** or **prepared statements**.

[Note: The MySQLi extension is designed to work with MySQL version 4.1.13 or newer.]

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['s_activId'] == 'om' && isset($_SESSION['s_userType']) && $_SESSION['s_userType'] == 'om')
{
    $dbName = "kal";
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",$dbName) or die("could not connect to database". mysqli_connect_error();
}
else if($_SESSION['s_activId'] == 'om' && isset($_SESSION['s_userType']) && $_SESSION['s_userType'] == 'om1')
{
    $dbName = "kal1";
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",$dbName) or die("could not connect to database". mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, probably it will help. The code is straight forward 
in order to debug your issue use

```
 echo print_r($_SESSION, true);
```

To see the values you gonna use.

```
<?php
session_start();

$sActivId = isset($_SESSION['s_activId']) ? $_SESSION['s_activId'] : "";
$sUserType = isset($_SESSION['s_userType']) ? $_SESSION['s_userType'] : ""; 
$dbName = "";

if($sActivId != 'om'){
    throw new Exception("The user is not valid or active");
}
switch($sUserType){
    case 'om': 
        $dbName = "kal";
        break;
    case 'om1':
        $dbName = "kal1";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
if(empty($dbName)){
    throw new Exception("The db Name is undefined");
}

$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$link){
    throw new Exception("'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()");
}

mysql_select_db($dbName) or die("colud not connect to database". mysql_error());


?>
```

Comment: check the values that you have in a $_SESSION

Comment: Array ( [s_activId] => om [s_userType] => om [s_adminuserid] => om [s_userId] => 1 )

Comment: You wrote  === I want to select a database on userid password condition === Does it mean that choice of DB you making according [s_userId]  variable ?